# Export Outlook 2003 Rules to text

Tags: export, microsoft-outlook-2003

I'm running into the rules size limit for Outlook 2003, so I want to merge/delete my rules. I want to be able to see them all as opposed to editing them one at a time. The export format for Outlook rules is some binary "*.rwz" file.

Is there a way to export Outlook rules into a text or excel file?

Comment: Odd that an Outlook ***2003*** question is still getting votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are out of luck... a classic MS proprietary format.

However, a subset of the rules wizard interface is supported via VBA - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206763.aspx for details.  You could script something up to export the rules as human-readable but it may well not cover all your rules.

Good luck!

Comment: That link is for Outlook 2007. The Outlook 2003 Object Model doesn't even have a Rule object, so I'm SOL.  Thanks anyway

Comment: @glenn-jackman Did you find a workaround to perform this task? I also want to make a list of all my rules to reorganize them.

Answer (score 1):

Free https://rwzreader.codeplex.com/
- Organize rules by highlighting one or more rules and dragging to reorder, or use Up/Down buttons
- Sort rules by highlighting two or more rules and clicking the sort button
- Save the organized RWZ file as a different file or save the rules directly to Outlook

Answer (score 1):

The library https://github.com/hughbe/OutlookRulesReader contains a specification and reference implementation library (in Swift) for reading and writing Outlook Rules Files

A full description of the format can be found [here](https://github.com/hughbe/OutlookRulesReader/raw/master/docs/RWZ%20Format.pdf)

Comment: I would love to be able to write my rules programmatically, does this project support writing, or just reading?

Answer (score 0):

I modified some code I found and have this macro to list out all Rules in tab-delimited format suitable for a spreadsheet.  Not elegant, perhaps, but it seems to work.  I also have another borrowed macro for finding out which rules apply to a given selected folder.

```
    Sub ListRules() ' Created: 20200726
        'Modified by www.jfkelley.com
        'I impose no copyright conditions on the parts of this macro that I wrote.  Enjoy.
        'Based on: http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/create-list-rules/
        'This will cull out all the Outlook Rules you have and print them out to a TXT file in your Temp directory.
        'It will also OPEN that TXT file using default editor (e.g., Notepad/Notepad++)
        'The data is tab-delimited so you can copy/paste it right into Excel.
        'It currently only features the 5 conditions of most interest to me,
        'but it should also enumerate any other conditions that are used in case you want to add those columns explicitly.
        
        Dim colStores As Outlook.Stores
        Dim oFileSys As Object
        Dim oStore As Outlook.Store
        Dim oRoot As Outlook.Folder
        Dim oCondition As Outlook.RuleCondition
        Dim oCondfrom As Outlook.RuleCondition
        Dim oAction As Outlook.RuleAction
        Dim colRules As Object
        Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule
        Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder
        Dim oMoveTarget As Outlook.Folder
        Dim sOutput As String
        Dim myVar As Variant
        
        Dim dR As Object
        Set dR = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dR.Add olConditionAccount, "olConditionAccount"
        dR.Add olConditionAnyCategory, "olConditionAnyCategory"
        dR.Add olConditionBody, "olConditionBody"
        dR.Add olConditionBodyOrSubject, "olConditionBodyOrSubject"
        dR.Add olConditionCategory, "olConditionCategory"
        dR.Add olConditionCc, "olConditionCc"
        dR.Add olConditionDateRange, "olConditionDateRange"
        dR.Add olConditionFlaggedForAction, "olConditionFlaggedForAction"
        dR.Add olConditionFormName, "olConditionFormName"
        dR.Add olConditionFrom, "olConditionFrom"
        dR.Add olConditionFromAnyRssFeed, "olConditionFromAnyRssFeed"
        dR.Add olConditionFromRssFeed, "olConditionFromRssFeed"
        dR.Add olConditionHasAttachment, "olConditionHasAttachment"
        dR.Add olConditionImportance, "olConditionImportance"
        dR.Add olConditionLocalMachineOnly, "olConditionLocalMachineOnly"
        dR.Add olConditionMeetingInviteOrUpdate, "olConditionMeetingInviteOrUpdate"
        dR.Add olConditionMessageHeader, "olConditionMessageHeader"
        dR.Add olConditionNotTo, "olConditionNotTo"
        dR.Add olConditionOnlyToMe, "olConditionOnlyToMe"
        dR.Add olConditionOOF, "olConditionOOF"
        dR.Add olConditionOtherMachine, "olConditionOtherMachine"
        dR.Add olConditionProperty, "olConditionProperty"
        dR.Add olConditionRecipientAddress, "olConditionRecipientAddress"
        dR.Add olConditionSenderAddress, "olConditionSenderAddress"
        dR.Add olConditionSenderInAddressBook, "olConditionSenderInAddressBook"
        dR.Add olConditionSensitivity, "olConditionSensitivity"
        dR.Add olConditionSentTo, "olConditionSentTo"
        dR.Add olConditionSizeRange, "olConditionSizeRange"
        dR.Add olConditionSubject, "olConditionSubject"
        dR.Add olConditionTo, "olConditionTo"
        dR.Add olConditionToOrCc, "olConditionToOrCc"
        dR.Add olConditionUnknown, "olConditionUnknown"
        
        
        'On Error Resume Next
        Set oFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        
        'Create a folder named Rules on your C drive or change the path to use an existing folder
        Dim fnp As String
        fnp = Environ("temp") & "\OLFilterList.txt"
        If oFileSys.FileExists(fnp) Then
            oFileSys.DeleteFile (fnp)
        End If
        Open fnp For Output As #1
        
        Set colStores = Application.Session.Stores
        Set oStore = colStores(1)
        Set oRoot = oStore.GetRootFolder
        Set colRules = oStore.GetRules
        Dim stHdr As String, stName As String, stToFolder As String, stFrom As String, stSenderAddress As String, stSentTo As String, stRecipientAddress As String, stOthers As String
        
        stHdr = "Order" & Chr(9) & "Name" & Chr(9) & "ToFolder" & Chr(9) & "From" & Chr(9) & "SenderAddress" & Chr(9) & "SentTo" & Chr(9) & "RecipientAddress" & Chr(9) & "OtherConditions"
        Print #1, stHdr
    
        
        For Each oRule In colRules
            stName = oRule.Name
            stToFolder = "??"
            stFrom = ""
            stSenderAddress = ""
            stSentTo = ""
            stRecipientAddress = ""
            stOthers = ""
            
    
            For Each oAction In oRule.Actions
                If oAction.Enabled = True Then
                    If oAction.ActionType = olRuleActionMoveToFolder Then
                        stToFolder = oAction.Folder.FolderPath
                    End If
                
                    'add more actions here
                
                End If
            Next
            
            For Each oCondition In oRule.Conditions
                If oCondition.Enabled = True Then
                    If oCondition.ConditionType = olConditionFrom Then
                        stFrom = oRule.Conditions.From.Recipients(1)
                    ElseIf oCondition.ConditionType = olConditionSenderAddress Then
                        For Each myVar In oRule.Conditions.SenderAddress.Address
                            If stSenderAddress <> "" Then stSenderAddress = stSenderAddress & "; "
                            stSenderAddress = stSenderAddress & myVar
                        Next
                    ElseIf oCondition.ConditionType = olConditionSentTo Then
                        For Each myVar In oRule.Conditions.SentTo.Recipients
                            If stSentTo <> "" Then stSentTo = stSentTo & "; "
                            stSentTo = stSentTo & myVar
                        Next
                    ElseIf oCondition.ConditionType = olConditionRecipientAddress Then
                        For Each myVar In oRule.Conditions.RecipientAddress.Address
                            If stRecipientAddress <> "" Then stRecipientAddress = stRecipientAddress & "; "
                            stRecipientAddress = stRecipientAddress & myVar
                        Next
                    Else
                        If stOthers <> "" Then stOthers = stOthers & "; "
                        stOthers = stOthers & dR(oCondition.ConditionType)
                    End If
                    
                    'add more ElseIf conditions above and follow the pattern for the header (above) and data (below).
                
                End If
            Next
            stOutput = (oRule.ExecutionOrder) & Chr(9) & stName & Chr(9) & stToFolder & Chr(9) & stFrom & Chr(9) & stSenderAddress & Chr(9) & stSentTo & Chr(9) & stRecipientAddress & Chr(9) & stOthers
            Print #1, stOutput
        Next
        Close #1
        Dim fso As Object
        Set fso = CreateObject("shell.application")
        sfile = fnp
        fso.Open (sfile)
    End Sub
    
    
     
     
    Sub EnumerateRelatedRules() ' Created 20200726
        'Source: https://techniclee.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/finding-rules-related-to-a-folder-in-outlook/
        'The author also had some code to make this a context-menu (right-click) item, but I couldn't make it work.
        'So: Just select a folder (or email in a folder) and use Developer tab -> Macros to run it.
        'Works nicely in conjunction with my other spreadsheet report on all the Outlook Rules.
        '  - Posted here: https://superuser.com/questions/92197/export-outlook-2003-rules-to-text/1571875#1571875
        Dim olkRul As Outlook.Rule, olkAct As Outlook.RuleAction, strRules As String
        For Each olkRul In Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
            For Each olkAct In olkRul.Actions
                If olkAct.ActionType = olRuleActionCopyToFolder Or olkAct.ActionType = olRuleActionMoveToFolder Then
                    If olkAct.Enabled Then
                        If olkAct.Folder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder Then  'olkCurrentFolder Then
                            strRules = strRules & olkRul.Name & vbCrLf
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
        If strRules = "" Then
            strRules = "None"
        End If
        MsgBox strRules, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Rules Related to this Folder"
        Set olkRul = Nothing
        Set olkAct = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: P.S. I'm using these macros in Outlook 365.  Over the years I've accumulated upwards of 350 rules!  Time for some weeding!